# TwitteR package failing to grab some tweets due to oauth error (but only some!)

Tags: r, twitter

I have the following code to scrape twitter accounts:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(NLP)
library(httr)
library(twitteR)
library(foreign)
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
library(base64enc)
library(caTools)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(plyr)

access_token<-"" #my credentials are here
access_secret<-""
consumer_key<-""
consumer_secret<-""

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

I then have a character list of users that I apply a function of userTimeline too in order to grab their tweets without having to enter all their usernames in individually.

The code works. I do get OAuth authentication and I am able to grab the vast majority of my users' tweets.

However, there are 7 users that return an OAuth error. They are: @ZestieHorsie, @jjadeceleste, @blondlyfe, @KamiObaro, @valmonella, @KeplinTinyman, and @PromissWright

These users are spaced out unevenly in my list, so I'm getting errors for *only* these 7 users and being able to grab the rest of them just fine. Note: this isn't an http404 error (there are a couple of those that I've fixed), it's specifically an OAuth error:

```
try(userTimeline("@jjadeceleste", n=1), silent=F)
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) : 
OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

Can anyone help me understand why some of the users get an error and some don't?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a reset? That seems to work for a lot of people with this problem. Regenerate the API key and secret. Also, can you run the demo and see if it works? Another possible solution is to try installing `base64enc`. https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/issues/74

Comment: Are those accounts private?

Comment: I have reset my API Key and Secret, but I don't understand why it would have an issue with only a few of the users in my collection of usernames.

I'm not sure if these accounts are private or not, but I don't think that the twitteR package necessarily differentiates? I don't have a public profile and it can grab all my tweets just fine (I used a separate twitter account for scraping, so it's not that I'm using the same OAuth of the account I'm scraping).
If by private you mean their name is blacked out, then I don't think that's the case. I found them through the search function.

Comment: as @cory pointed out, all those accounts are private, except '@blondlyfe', so twitter won't return information regarding them. You can check this by going to twitter.com/@username.

'@blondlyfe' hasn't tweeted since 2014, so her tweets may be falling out of a timeframe restriction if you have one in place.